# Multiple sensors on a single serial port

Tags: serial, uart

I want to use a single serial UART port on an mcu to communicate with two different sensors. I have connected both the sensors' TX lines together to mcu's RX line and vice versa. I am switching the sensors ON and OFF in such a manner that at no point in time are both the sensors being powered. Would this configuration work?

Comment: No. A quick search would have revealed multiple answers to similar questions. An additional problem with what you suggest is that the powered-down receivers will probably clamp their RX and TX pins near ground through their ESD protection circuits.

Comment: No, but you can mux the signals with a MAX399, assuming that everything in your system is using modern RS232 levels (<= +/- 5V). The RS232 spec allows much higher levels, but these are rarely used now. https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/588